# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx'

Tags: python-3.x, networkx, spyder

9 in spyder IDE. I want to import networkx for my project.

So I installed it using  `pip install networkx`. It got successfully installed. But when I try to import it it shows `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'networkx'`.

I searched many posts. All I gone through advices to use pip install networkx.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You might be installing the module in another virtual enviornement (if you are even using them) to check that, run `pip freeze` and check if the list contains networkx. And if it does, make sure to run the program in the same venv with the module installed.

Comment: (*Spyder maintainer here*) How did you install Spyder?